# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null que significa?

Tags: java

Estoy obteniendo un error y no entiendo en donde lo tengo, dice que es al importar el archivo sin embargo después de revisar todo sigo sin entender.

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Éste es el método cargar info de la interfaz:

```
 public void cargarInfo ()
 {

        JFileChooser archivo = new JFileChooser("./data");
        archivo.setDialogTitle("Escoger Dificultad");


        int resultado = archivo.showOpenDialog(this);

        if(resultado == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION);
        {
            cueva=null;
            panelTablero.removeAll();
            panelTablero.revalidate();
            panelTablero.repaint();
            archivoNivel = archivo.getSelectedFile( );
        }
    try
    {
        cueva=new Cueva(archivoNivel);
        //panelControles.refrescar();
        panelTablero.setSize(ancho,alto);
        panelTablero.inicializar(cueva.darFilas(),cueva.darColumnas(),cueva.darBitmap());
        //panelTablero.iluminar();
        int ancho = (darCueva().darColumnas()*51);  
        int alto=(darCueva().darFilas()*52);
        int anchoP=ancho+228;
        int altoP=alto+235;

        setSize(anchoP,altoP);

        validate();
        repaint();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());

    }
    }
```

Y éste es el del mundo:

```
public Cueva(File archivo) throws Exception
{
    Properties datos = cargarInfo(archivo);
    String numeroFilas1 = datos.getProperty( "filas" );
    filas = Integer.parseInt( numeroFilas1 );
    String columnas1 = datos.getProperty( "columnas" );
    columnas = Integer.parseInt( columnas1 );
    inicializar(datos);
 }
```

Comment: Si podés probalo reemplazando numetoFilas1 por un nro que quieras, lo mismo para columnas1,  dale números cualquiera y si va el error ya sabemos donde está, probablemente te esté llegando un null a la que querés pasear,  y como acepta String cono parámetros no te tira error ze compilación pero si te dice que está esperando un nro y no un null

Comment: El código que nos muestras nos concuerda. La definición de tu método `cargarInfo` es un void, pero en el constructor de `Cueva` lo usas como si devolviera un `Properties`. No encaja. También, por favor incluye los detalles del error completos, o sea la pila de llamadas también, no solo el mensaje de error.

Comment: @OscarGarcia La solución a los errores no es ùnicamente agregar manejo de exceptions, es encontrar que provoca este problema.

Comment: Realiza el [tour] del sitio @user69155 y no olvides crear tus preguntas en base a [ask].

Comment: Ya tienes la respuesta detallando el motivo por el que se produce, el origen probable y cómo solucionarlo mediante bloques `try/catch` y comprobaciones adicionales. Si tienes alguna duda más sobre este tema házmela saber en un comentario aquí o en la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

La excepción [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) se lanza cuando:

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

En castellano:

> Se lanza para indicar que la aplicación ha intentado convertir una cadena a uno de los tipos numéricos, pero la cadena no tiene el formato apropiado.

En la documentación de [Integer.Integer()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer%28java.lang.String%29) puedes comprobar que se usa dicha excepción para indicar que la cadena de caracteres que se le pasa como parámetro no es un número.

Te recomiendo reforzar el código con bloques `try/catch`:

```
public Cueva(File archivo) throws Exception
{
    Properties datos = cargarInfo(archivo);
    String numeroFilas1 = datos.getProperty( "filas" );
    try {
        filas = Integer.parseInt( numeroFilas1 );
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        /* Qué hacer en caso de que no sea un número correcto */
    }
    String columnas1 = datos.getProperty( "columnas" );
    try {
        columnas = Integer.parseInt( columnas1 );
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        /* Qué hacer en caso de que no sea un número correcto */
    }
    inicializar(datos);
}
```

Además, parece que todo viene de que no existe dicha propiedad. Como puedes ver en la documentación de [Properties.getProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) te devolverá `null` si ésta no existe, y por eso te aparece eso en la excepción.

Una forma de detectar que no existe la propiedad y generar una excepción para indicarlo sería:

```
public Cueva(File archivo) throws Exception
{
    Properties datos = cargarInfo(archivo);
    String numeroFilas1 = datos.getProperty( "filas" );
    if (numeroFilas1 == null) {
        throw new Exception("La propiedad 'filas' no está definida");
    }
    try {
        filas = Integer.parseInt( numeroFilas1 );
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        /* Qué hacer en caso de que no sea un número correcto */
    }
    String columnas1 = datos.getProperty( "columnas" );
    if (columnas1 == null) {
        throw new Exception("La propiedad 'columnas' no está definida");
    }
    try {
        columnas = Integer.parseInt( columnas1 );
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        /* Qué hacer en caso de que no sea un número correcto */
    }
    inicializar(datos);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. Ya lo he agregado.